# Javascript foreach in C3JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, c3.js

I have the following graph :

[image]

As you can see there are different "bubbles" on it. Now i want to determine the size for each bubble from this array :

```
[50656, 74775, 74134, 74318, 77090, 79558, 80879, 66409, 79394, 70568, 65741, 75617, 72875, 75642, 74860, 74572, 56873, 76395, 92584, 59884, 63883, 73079, 68963, 60745, 68672, 69265, 75852, 79526, 55839, 65724, 56244, 57881, 43969, 51164, 49105, 42654, 45248, 38664, 49189, 44962, 56116, 49088, 33534, 26759, 44963, 50152, 52880, 77049, 70816, 83561, 82987, 65752, 63452, 73085, 78574, 69719, 79643, 69024, 63256, 69749, 65890, 74162, 67179, 71524, 81191, 78711, 61509, 64361, 71754, 63657, 66497, 59616, 73892, 70820, 64589, 65686, 74687, 67879, 50645, 71913, 68082, 59279, 64530, 49948, 50541, 56983, 64402, 73220, 67787, 79476, 74849, 49940, 69804, 83774, 69927, 69523, 75300, 84355, 81397, 94328…]
```

Each of this array values must determine the size of an invidual bubble.

When i do the following in c3js point function :

```
  point: {
        r: function (d) {
          for (var j = 0; j < getParkingDuration().length; j++) {
            return getParkingDuration()[j] / 10000;
          }
        }
      }
```

I also tried it this way :

```
 var parking_duur_hensbergen = getParkingDuration();

        chart = c3.generate({
          point: {
            r: function (d) {
              for (var j = 0; j < parking_duur_hensbergen.length; j++) {
                console.log(parking_duur_hensbergen[j]);
                return parking_duur_hensbergen[j] / 10000;
              }
            }
          }
```

It is only returning the first value of the loop. So all the bubble sizes are the same.

[image: All bubbles same size here]
**
My question is, how can i determine the size of each bubble from the array values?**

Comment: What does `getParkingDuration()` do? If it returns the array, call it once and put the results in a variable, then iterate over the variable.

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes the function getParkingDuration() is returning the array. Thanks for your answer will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event onrendered like this:

```
    onrendered: function () {
            var $$ = this;
            var circles = $$.getCircles();
            for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < circles[i].length; j++) {
                    $$.getCircles(j).style("r", (Math.random()*10)^0);
                }
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/87htjapx/